# How to use dagger qualifier annotations to provide different OkHttpClient builders?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger

I'm trying to use dagger qualifiers to provide different types of OkHttpClient.Builder in my android application. For instance I have two annotations namely @Authorized and @WithTime, each of which should add some interceptor to the client builder.

I want to be able to get different builders (add different interceptors) by just annotating the provide methods. But I don't know how to go about doing so when I have more than one annotation.

This is what I previously did when I only needed one annotation (@Authorized). But now I might require more types of clients and this is not possible.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Authorized
OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClientBuilderWithAuthorization(...)
```

```
@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClientBuilder(...)
```

Answer (score 5):

Dagger is built on a standard of **[JSR 330: Dependency Injection for Java](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)**. So you can use those annotations and it will be fully supported. For this same reason, you do not need to use the `@Qualifier` explicitly. You can use `@Named` annotation which itself has `@Qualifier` annotations.

On your first entry , add `@Named("authorized")` and on second, add `@Named("basic")`. You can add additional implementations in a similar fashion. Now when you need to inject your instance use the same annotation to identify the type.
So your overall code becomes,

Authorized :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("authorized")
OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClientBuilderWithAuthorization(...)
```

Basic:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("basic")
OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClientBuilder(...)
```

To inject `authorized` type of instance, now you can use

```
 @Inject 
 @Named("authorized") 
 OkHttpClient.Builder authorizedBuilder;
```

Similarly to inject `basic`, you can use

```
 @Inject 
 @Named("basic") 
 OkHttpClient.Builder basicBuilder;
```

For more details on how to use the dagger, visit **[dagger users guide](https://dagger.dev/users-guide)**

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this 
this is how you'll create your qualifier
`@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER,
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
annotation class Authorized()`
and when you access it you have to annotate your provider fun in module like this
`@JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @@YourPackagetoQualifier("Authorized")
    OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClientBuilderWithAuthorization(...)`

Answer (score 1):

first , declare your constant :

```
const val okHttpClientWithCertificatePinner = "okHttpClientWithCertificatePinner"
const val okHttpClientWithOutCertificatePinner = "okHttpClientWithOutCertificatePinner"

const val retrofitWithCertificatePinner = "retrofitWithCertificatePinner"
const val retrofitWithOutCertificatePinner = "retrofitWithOutCertificatePinner"
```

then in your module :

```
@Module
class RestClientModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(okHttpClientWithOutCertificatePinner)
    internal fun provideOkHttpClientWithoutPinner(
        context: Context,
        headersInterceptor: HeadersInterceptor,
        responseCodeInterceptor: ResponseCodeInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
    //...
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(okHttpClientWithCertificatePinner)
    internal fun provideOkHttpClientWithPinner(
        context: Context,
        headersInterceptor: HeadersInterceptor,
        responseCodeInterceptor: ResponseCodeInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
    //...
    }

}
```

and add retrofit provider :

```
@Module
class RestClientModule {
        /*
        ...
        */

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(retrofitWithOutCertificatePinner)
    internal fun provideRetrofit(
        @Named(okHttpClientWithOutCertificatePinner)
        client: OkHttpClient,
        gson: Gson
    ): Retrofit {
    //...
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(retrofitWithCertificatePinner)
    internal fun provideRetrofitWithPinner(
        @Named(okHttpClientWithCertificatePinner)
        client: OkHttpClient,
        gson: Gson
    ): Retrofit {
    //...
    }
```

}

and finally , provide your apis :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideNotificationsApi(
    @Named(retrofitWithCertificatePinner)
    retrofit: Retrofit
) = retrofit.create(NotificationsApi::class.java)

@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideCommonApi(
    @Named(retrofitWithOutCertificatePinner)
    retrofit: Retrofit
) = retrofit.create(CommonApi::class.java)
```